# XCode9: code signing blocked mmap() while running on device

Tags: xcode9

I encountered the following issue after upgrading to XCode9 (Well I could not completely isolate the cause because I re-generated the certificate right after upgrading for enabling Push Service) :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/apowo.framework/apowo
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/2CD5CA32-1DAF-423B-B921-024DCBEE2AF0/picatown.app/picatown
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2CD5CA32-1DAF-423B-B921-024DCBEE2AF0/XXXX.app/Frameworks/apowo.framework/apowo: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2CD5CA32-1DAF-423B-B921-024DCBEE2AF0/XXXX.app/Frameworks/apowo.framework/apowo'
```

There are several similar posts over SO but I believe it might be caused by something new. In fact the original issue was not on XXX.framework but libswiftcore, and after I have done all the suggestions on SO the error came from my own libraries. And here is what I have tried:

- clean
- delete the derived data
- restart XCode, Mac, and my phone
- delete all the certificates and recreate again
- delete the framework references (and the binaries as well) from the project and re-add

None of them works.

Some additional data is I am using jenkins and fastlane to manage the build. The XCode project is re-created every time when the job runs. The same job runs well on another machine which is on XCode 8 and nothing breaks (runs after re-creation of the certs so it is with the new certs).

I thought it was about the libraries and I rebuilt them on XCode 9. The newly built libs were also in the XCode 8 built app and worked well but not on XCode 9.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any solution or update?

Comment: well, it turns out to be the certificate issue. I chose "Always allow" for the root certificate by following one article. However it should be the default setting

Comment: @YANGLei, thank you! your comment should be the right answer.

Comment: @SoheilB.Marvasti Oh yeah. Glad it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried the following step and it's working:
In `XCode -> Build Phase -> Linked frameworks and libraries`: choose your particular framework status from required to optional.

And it should work ;)

Comment: It fixes my bug, too. I wonder what's the reason?
Maybe related to the code sign inside WebRTC?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/fXP9FjDiook

Answer (score 3):

I was having a very similar issue which ended up being a coding signing / Certificating issue. This article goes over two possible solutions in depth. For me, it came down to changing my Developer Certificate's trust levels.

Open Keychain Access: **My Certificates > "Right Click" Certificate > get info > Trust > When using this certificates > Use System Defaults**

"When using this certificates" should go from Use Custom Settings > Use System Defaults

https://blog.supereasyapps.com/how-to-fix-iphone-and-ipad-app-codesign-crashes-using-an-apple-developer-profile/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, and no matter how many times I recreated the certificate, cleaned the project or toggled the "use system defaults" vs "always trust" setting in the certificate — nothing helped.

What did help is noticing that while I had an Apple Worldwide Developer Relations CA in the keychain, my developer certificate was still "signed by an unknown authority" (only shows up when I double click it, there is no red cross near it in the list like for the expired ones).
It turns out apple has 5 different WWDG CAs — https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ You may want to check which was used to sign your profile (Issuer Name -> Organizational Unit: Gx) and download the appropriate one (or all of them). In my case, for example, I only had G1 installed, while a new certificate auto-created by XCode was signed by G3 that was missing in my system. Installing G3 (download and double-click or drop into the keychain window) solved the problem and I was able to run the application on my phone again.